# Publish page content to both DB & File System

Tags: web8

Is it possible to decide which page be publish to DB and which page be publish to file system case by case in the same publication?

Some of our page's content need to be explored by API, which can be consumed by other applications. But we don't want to push all pages to DB since performance reason.

Comment: I believe you can specify an item type to publish to a broker db or filesystem based on the extension. Would that help ? eg publish all pages with extension .xxx to the filesystem, and publish all pages with exension .yyy to the broker db

Comment: Could you please detail a bit the extension here? Is it the File extension be configured in page template?

Comment: indeed, i mean the extension as specified by the page template
and in cd_storage_conf, you would define something like this

<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xxx" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="DB_storage_id" /> and <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".yyy" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="FS_storage_id" />

Comment: @HaraldHoffelinck, I suggest that you go ahead and post the comment as an answer :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the cd_storage_conf.xml, you can specify an item type to publish to a broker db or filesystem based on the extension.

You would define something like this

```
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".xxx" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="DB_storage_id" />
<Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".yyy" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="FS_storage_id" />
```

Than all you need to do is create a page template with file extension xxx and a page template with file extension yyy, and you're set.

This would enable you to specify where your page would be published to, based on the selected page template.

Comment: I suppose we need to configure it at Deployer server side right? We already have dozen exist page extensions, which all go to file system. If we just add one item and configure it to DB, will all other pages still go to file system by default? And besides read it from DB directly, is there any API we can use to load page data from DB?

Comment: you need to configure this both in the deployer server, but also in your web app, as both applications need to know where to put or read the page content from). There definitely is an API to read these pages from the DB, and certainly create sql scripts yourself to get it. Check some of the dd4t source code to see how they are doing this - https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/blob/develop/dd4t-providers/src/main/java/org/dd4t/providers/impl/BrokerPageProvider.java#L98 (this sample is using java, but you could do it using .NET as well)

Comment: and to answer your first question, yes, if you add a new extension, and tell the deployer to store that extension in DB, all your other extensions will remain publishing to the file system as before.